# YouTube Autosuggest API - where to find samples or documentation?

Tags: api, video, autocomplete, youtube, mixer

I want to create a YouTube video search box with the same autocomplete feature.
Any idea where can I find samples or and documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can get the JSON of the autocomplete searching for the word "obama" using the following HTTP GET query:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&client=youtube&hjson=t&ds=yt&jsonp=window.yt.www.suggest.handleResponse&q=obama&cp=3

I've seen this call using the youtube and watching the generated HTTP queries with Firefox Live HTTP Headers extension.

I hope it helps.